# I'm stuck in the Select Circle in Blender 3.4.1. Nothing helps

Tags: 3d-view, interface

I want to ask how I can switch back to Select Box in Blender.
I tried pressing  <kbd>W</kbd>, also pressed <kbd>Esc</kbd>, <kbd>Right Mouse Button</kbd>. I tried pressing <kbd>Q</kbd>, and also tried pressing <kbd>C</kbd>. I also reinstalled Blender.

The keyboard settings are standard. Nothing helped. Can anyone tell me how to remove it?

Comment: It **should** be the Esc key and the W key **should** toggle between the selection options at any time so something's obviously wrong. If you hold the left mouse button down with the cursor over the top left selection icon on the toolbar you should get a dropdown menu with the four selection options that you can click. Please post an image of your Blender window which you can create from the Window > Save Screenshot menu and then follow https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post..

Comment: It would also help us if you could share your Blend file via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to add a link to the file.

Answer (score 0):

As @John Eason suggested, you ***should*** have an icon in your toolbar for choosing what tools you have. If you can't see the toolbar, try hitting <kbd>T</kbd>

[image]